# How to remove double quotes from csv file

Tags: python, csv

When I open the generated csv file there are some unwanted double quotes in the column track_uri that I cannot remove. Please can you tell me how to remove them?

The code of the program is here:

```
import json
import csv
import os

input_data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\ProjectsDesktop\\dataset\\'
output_data_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Projects\\'


p_t_cols = ["pid", "track_uri"]
list_track_uri=[]


for filename in os.listdir(input_data_dir):
    if('.json' in filename):
        filepath = input_data_dir + filename
        print(filepath)
        data = json.load(open(filepath))
        playlists = data["playlists"]
        for p in playlists:
            line = [p["name"], p["collaborative"], p["pid"], p["modified_at"], p["num_tracks"], p["num_albums"], p["num_followers"]]

            pid = p["pid"]
            tracks = p["tracks"]
            for t in tracks:
                line = [t["artist_name"], t["track_uri"], t["artist_uri"], t["track_name"], t["album_uri"], t["duration_ms"], t["album_name"]]

                track_uri = t["track_uri"]


                line = [pid, track_uri]

                list_track_uri.append(track_uri)
uris= set(list_track_uri)


import random
final_uris=set(random.sample(uris, 500))
print(len(final_uris))
final_uris = ','.join(final_uris)



path=r'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\ML Datasets\\'
filenames = os.listdir(path)
with open('submission.csv', mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as accounts:
    writer=csv.writer(accounts)


    for filename in sorted(filenames):
        if filename.startswith("challenge_set") and filename.endswith(".json"):
            fullpath = os.sep.join((path, filename))
            f = open(fullpath)
            js = f.read()
            f.close()
            mpd_slice = json.loads(js)
            writer.writerow(["pid",  "track_uri"])
            for playlist in mpd_slice["playlists"]:
                final_uris.replace('"', '')
                writer.writerow([playlist["pid"], final_uris])
```

[Here is a screenshot from the output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HntUC.png)

Comment: Please update to post *text* **not** an image.

Comment: Double quotes are part of the CSV format, so you do not want to remove them.   If the value being output happens to contain a comma, then the value is output in double quotes so that the reader knows to treat that comma as part of the value rather than a column separator.  Here’s the RFC 4180 standard for CSV files : https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
writer.writerow([playlist["pid"], final_uris])
```

to

```
writer.writerow([playlist["pid"], *final_uris])
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours I found the solution to this problem and I post it if anyone in the future will need it.

I changed this line into this by adding quotechar= " "

```
writer=csv.writer(accounts,  quotechar = " ")
```

Thank you all for your help.